# React Native: Different headers for different screens in Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I am using `@react-navigation/stack` version `^5.5.1`. I am trying to have different headers on different screens in my Stack Navigation. For example, on `Master`, I want no header, i.e., `headerMode="none"`; on `Home`, I want a custom header, and on `Details` I want a different custom header. How do I achieve this? This is my current code:

```
const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Master" component={ Master } />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={ Home } />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={ Details } />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured it out.

First, put `headerMode="screen"` on the `Stack.Navigator`. This moves control of the header to each screen. Then use the syntax as shown below for each individual screen.

```
const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="screen">
        <Stack.Screen name="Master" component={ Master } options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={ Home } options={{ headerTitle: props => <MyCustomHeader {...props} /> }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={ Details } options={{ headerTitle: props => <MyOtherCustomHeader {...props} /> }}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```